# How to Pull all the data from the Paginated REST API in ADF pipeline

Tags: rest, azure-data-factory

I have one REST api which given me JASON result as per below:

```json
[
    {
        "id": 380595,
        "employee_number": "",
        "first_name": "xxxx",
        "last_name": "xx",
        "job_title": "",
        "email": "xxxxxx",
        "phish_prone_percentage": 0.0,
        "phone_number": "xxxxxx",
        "extension": "",
        "mobile_phone_number": "",
        "location": null,
        "division": "",
        "manager_name": null,
        "manager_email": null,
        "provisioning_managed": true,
        "provisioning_guid": null
    }
]
```

My API something like this: `https://eu.api.XXXXXX.com/v1/users?page=1&per_page=1`

I saw lots of video where they have total count or they have next page URL, but here in my API I have nothing showing. Can someone please explain me how I can fetch all pages.

From the source system I know I have around 2700 records for Users.

I build one dataset and copy activity and able to fetch the first page.

Comment: The documentation for the API will have the paging instructions?

Comment: In their document they mention only two parameters like Page and Per_Page. Page for which page no and Per_Page for no of records in per page. Here is the link for their API documentation. https://developer.knowbe4.com/rest/reporting#tag/Response-Format

Answer (score 1):

To Pull all the data from the Paginated REST API in ADF pipeline you have two ways. using REST API connector pagination

**1. Using REST API connector pagination**
As you know how many pages there in your paginated rest Api.

- create the source data set as below in your case.

```json
Base URL: https://eu.api.XXXXXX.com/v1/users]
Relateive URL:?page={offset}&per_page=1
```

[image]

- Use pagination rule to paginate8 as below.
  -- If you know how many records to be paginated
  [image]
  -- If you don't know how many records to be paginated need to add end condition as if particular node doesn't exist
  [image]

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Thank you Pratik for your detail answer.

Comment: I tried to implement your solution but still getting the error.  Here are the details.

Comment: When I using the first option with Range I am getting only 500 records. I did like this paginationRules": {
            "AbsoluteUrl.{offset}": "RANGE:1:8000:500" In my API document they mention Per_Page limit 500 records. Is there any idea why I am not getting the rest records please.? Thank againg for your help.

Comment: And with second option with EndCondition I am getting the below error.  Error details
Copy data1
Error code

RestMoreThanOneObjectsReturned

Failure typeUser configuration issue
Activity ID
-Details
ErrorCode=RestMoreThanOneObjectsReturned,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=More than one object returned.\r\n'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject]',Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.ClientLibrary,'

Comment: As endcondition try using `$.id` with not exist

Comment: Hi Pratik, I tried just now and getting the same error: Failure happened on 'Source' side. ErrorCode=RestCallFailedWithClientError,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=Rest call failed with client error, status code 429 429, please check your activity settings.
Request URL: https://eu.api.knowbe4.com/v1/users/?page=50&per_page=1.
Response: Retry later
,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.ClientLibrary,'

Comment: Hi @Pratik Lad, Is there any further assistance you do for me please.. Thanks Imran

Comment: as you know you have 8000 records and per page 500 records are getting displayed the pages are 8000/500=16 so the pagination rule will look like `paginationRules": { "AbsoluteUrl.{offset}": "RANGE:1:16:1"`