ADF Dynamic content for pagination rules
Using copy activity with the pagination and Query parameters Range.It works fine when I hardcode Range as Start=1 and End = 41 and offset as 1 (going page by page).However, I do not know what the "end" argument is and it is calculated (from previous activity).  So, that Dynamic content seems handy, but I can't find how enter it.

Initially, I thought of using the "@range(1, 41)" function, but it is not it.  Copy activity errors out with the message "The property 'paginationRules' is invalid or missing.,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.ClientLibrary,'"
And technically function @range() returns a physical array ([1, 2,3..41]), that really not applicable.  Please, help

Check this link  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77060467/how-to-pull-all-the-data-from-the-paginated-rest-api-in-adf-pipeline

@SQL006 !!  Perfect !!! Thank you !!! Leaving that "End" blank was what I was looking for.
But, how in the world, would I figure that out from documentation and especially given that option "Use Dynamic Content" ?

Yeah I know the dynamic expression  cause confusion , I also face the same situation which I asked here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78014096/pagination-rule-in-adf-rest-api-copy-activity. From the MS doc you can find the example  related to your problem https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-rest?tabs=data-factory#example-4variables-are-in-absoluteurlqueryparametersheaders-the-end-variable-is-not-pre-defined-and-the-end-condition-is-based-on-the-response

I agree with @SQL006 that you need to use End condition for the after Range if you don't know about the number of pages in your REST API.

After giving Range, give the JSON object and the value like above as per your REST API.
The Result data will be till the last page of the API like below.


would I figure that out from documentation and especially given that option "Use Dynamic Content" ?

It is used in the scenarios where you want to give the Query parameters or Absolute URIs dynamically. It means, when you are using REST API in iterations and your Absolute URI is changing for every iteration, you can use the dynamic expression to build the required JSON object key (the value of this key should be next URI) as per the API.
This is a sample demo where @item() value will be changing in every iteration and new JSON object key will be generated dynamically.


Thank you.  Yes, I picked it right away when previous responder answered about the end condition.  I just did not put 2+2 initially.  I guess, comes with experience.

Now, the challenge is to make the same happen in the mapping data flow !!! They don't have 'Range' as an option

I saw you raised another question, I will check that one.
